# How one tests http requests in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift, ios8, xctest

In ruby I used to test http requests with vcr gem which recorded the request so the tests didn't send request to real host. Is there anything like this in iOS8 world?
The requests I want to test really need to be recorded since those requests may be outdated in some time and will return some other response

P.S. It would be great if it was some default Apple/iOS approach/library like XCTest for testing in general

Comment: Try using "NSURLProtocol", https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/index.html.

Using NSURLProtocol you can intercept the HTTP requests, match and provide the cahed responses back.

Comment: well, in this case I will need to implement the whole framework just to record the response while I'd rather use some already written library

Comment: https://github.com/luisobo/Nocilla

Comment: this one stubs the response, but the problem is that I have to do it manually and I want the library to record that request itself. And when the next time I do the request, it should use the recorded data not real connection to server and I should be able to run it  even without internet

Comment: if you would read it carefully you will see that this is answered in the readme

Comment: but still, I will need to record every request with `curl -is` before using it in tests and this is not so convenient. Besides, the day, I'll want to update my recorded requests will be just a pain since I will need to re-record every request again manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like OHHTTPStubs or Nocilla or AMY server. All of them essentially use NSURLProtocol to intercept your request and allow you to designate a response. We used OHHTTPStubs but pick the one with the feature set closest to your use case.

Here's an example of an OHHTTPStubs implementation in a unit test for a service that talks to a single REST endpoint:

```
NSString *loadRoomJSON = @{ @"key" : @"value" }; /* some JSON */
NSNumber identifier = @1;
[OHHTTPStubs stubRequestsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSURLRequest *request) {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v1/user/%@/room", identifier];
    XCTAssert([request.URL.relativePath containsString:url], @"Expected certain URL");
    return YES;
} andRespond:^OHHTTPStubsResponse *(NSURLRequest *request) {
    return [OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithJSONObject:loadRoomJSON statusCode:200 headers:nil];
}];

XCTestExpectation *loadPromise = [self expectation:@"Room loaded"];
[service loadRoomOnSucceed:^(Room *room) {
    // Do your asserts here.  For us, the JSON is mapped to an object
    // so for example you could assert that the object is mapped correctly
    [loadPromise fulfill];
} onFail:^(NSError *error) {
    expect(error).to.beNil();
}];

[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1.0 handler:^(NSError *error) {
    expect(error).to.beNil();
}];
```

In reality our tests are shorter since we write wrapper/helpers to make it read better so this is an exploded-out version.  Should give you the general idea.  OHHTTPStubs (if you use it) has helper functions to load responses directly from files as well.

Comment: How did you use that library? Did you do the requests manually, store the responses there and then used the saved file in tests?

Comment: @arthur.borisow the library just gives you mocking behavior.  How you generate the mock response is the dev's job.  You could craft it based upon docs, copy a live response and modify that, whatever.  I edited answer to include an example of a JSON endpoint test with OHHTTPStubs.  Same general pattern would apply for other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if I understood you correct. But if I understand you right, you should be able to use `XCTest` to test your request and response.

```
class Tests:XCTestCase{

    func testing(){
        var expectation = self.expectationWithDescription("Your request")

        var url = NSURL(string: "http://yourUrl.com")

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            if let httpRes = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                println("status code=",httpRes.statusCode)
                //200 means OK
                if httpRes.statusCode == 200 {
                    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
                }
            }else{
                println("error \(error)")
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer but that's not what I am looking for. Please see this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551084/how-one-tests-http-requests-in-ios-8#comment45424710_28551084